# jstl returns null back on servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm creating createEdit.jsp , the page which can handle both edit and create new users. 
Here is my jstl tag

```
<c:if test="${ pageAction == 'edit' }"> 
<input type="text" name="loginU" disabled="disabled" value="${userEdit.login}"/>
</c:if>
```

if this page is 'edit' I have disabled textfield with login (e.g. 'user' ) shown.
The problem is - this value can't be posted further as request expires. 
And When I'm trying to get loginU on my servlet I get null.

```
String loginU = req.getParameter("loginU");

out.println("login: " + loginU);
```

What should I do to pass this ${userEdit.login} further

Comment: `disabled` inputs don't get posted, `readonly` ones do...

Comment: Why do you think that this is a JSTL problem? JSTL does not run in webbrowser at all. Rightclick page in browser and choose *View Source*. Right, it's just one and all HTML, exactly as produced by JSP on your own command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputs` marked as `disabled` do not get POSTed, ones marked as `readonly` do however, so you could:

```
<c:if test="${ pageAction == 'edit' }"> 
    <input type="text" name="loginU" readonly="readonly" value="${userEdit.login}"/>
</c:if>
```

The alternative, which may look better, is to spit the value out and add a hidden input to send the value:

```
<c:if test="${ pageAction == 'edit' }">
    <p>${userEdit.login}</p> 
    <input type="hidden" name="loginU" value="${userEdit.login}"/>
</c:if>
```